# operator is not unique. Could not choose a best candidate operator. You might need to add explicit type casts

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have this query that just selects the difference between two dates:

```
select date_part('day', 'toDate' - 'fromDate') from "Reservation" where "reservationID" = 1;
```

but this is giving me this error:

> operator is not unique. Could not choose a best candidate operator.
>   You might need to add explicit type casts.

How can I fix this?

P.S. This is how I created "Reservations" table:

```
CREATE TABLE "Reservation"
(
  "reservationID" serial NOT NULL,
  "fromDate" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT '-  infinity'::timestamp without time zone,
  "toDate" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT '-infinity'::timestamp without time zone,
  "staffID" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  "customerID" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  "roomID" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  CONSTRAINT "PK_public.Reservation" PRIMARY KEY ("reservationID"),
  CONSTRAINT "FK_public.Reservation_public.Customer_customerID" FOREIGN KEY    ("customerID")
  REFERENCES "Customer" ("customerID") MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT "FK_public.Reservation_public.Room_roomID" FOREIGN KEY ("roomID")
  REFERENCES "Room" ("roomID") MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT "FK_public.Reservation_public.Staff_staffID" FOREIGN KEY ("staffID")
  REFERENCES "Staff" ("staffID") MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

Comment: You should avoid quoted identifiers - they are much more trouble than they are worth it (and personally I think all those necessary double quotes just make the statements much harder to read)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for suggestion. The thing is I was using ASP.NET code first approach. So all the database tables were created by ASP.NET and I don't know why it put all those double quotes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cant't use `'` you need `"` instead for columns name

```
select date_part('day', "toDate" - "fromDate") from "Reservation" where "reservationID" = 1;
```

Comment: I get `column "todate" does not exist` error if I remove those

Comment: Can you include `Reservation` table structure?

Comment: Added `create` script in the question

Comment: @JohnyStark `"todate"` is a different column name than the one you have: `"toDate"`. See the manual for details: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: @Parado I swear I tried with `"` too but it said `column "toDate" does not exist`. This is killing me. But after you said so, it worked :) Thank you! Any ideas why it said `columd does not exist`

Comment: @JohnyStark I'm glad I could help you :) To understand why I got an error- consider a documentation from `a_horse_with_no_name` gave you above.

Comment: 'abc' is actually a string, while "abc" is the name of a database column (or a view, a table or any other database object). This is according to the SQL standard. So 'abc' will never give you a "column does not exist", because it doesn't refer to any column. The data type is always text, so you cannot subtract 'abc' - 'def', but you can subtract "abc" - "def" if those two colums exist and have appropriate data types. Subtracting two timestamp-columns have interval as return type.